# Compiling an old Swift project with CocoaPods packages failed after conversion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

I'm trying to fix it for a couple of hours, but still without success.
I've got an iOS project from a company that needs some updates on that app. It was written in swift 2.3

My XCode version is 8.3.3 - when I opened the project, I got a message I have to convert the code to Swift 3

As a first thing, I updated pods dependencies

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Here is my podfile if there's anybody interested to know

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.2' #there was '8' when I got the code
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!
workspace 'NaKoleIPesky'

target 'NaKoleIPesky' do

pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'HanekeSwift'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'SwiftLoader'
pod 'GooglePlacesAutocomplete', git: 'https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete'
pod 'FRHyperLabel'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'GoogleConversionTracking'

end
```

I tried to convert the code (both pods packages and our code) to Swift3 via the Convert tool, but it returned with the error "Convert: Failed", popping up about 1700 buildtime errors. This is the list of files that tried to converts.

[image]

I press okay, but there's still a lot of compiler errors. Like these

[image]
[image]

or this one
[image]

probably wrongly converted, the original code was

```
  self.handleResponse(data, response: response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, error: error, completion: completion)
```

Is the convert tool working bad? What can I do in this case? I don't want to rewrite all the code and fix 680 errors before I can compile something that was working before. I tried to Google a lot about this problem but no useful solutions were found.

Comment: You just **have** to rewrite the code, Swift updates are (quite) breaking and the migrator can't migrate everything. See ["known migration issues" section in this article](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/)

Comment: Try convert your project to Swift 3 only, do not touch the pod lib, probably its just wrong detection of the swift version

Comment: I would recommend to *not* convert the pods, you should update the pods (assuming that the pod itself is supporting Swift 3).

Comment: Why don't using Xcode 7 ?

Comment: @Vahid because Xcode 7 is older, I update regullary

Comment: @AhmadF but considering there's no update to these libraries, the only way to fix this is to fix it all manually? wow, that's a bit of dirty work there... If they at least let you select to stay with Swift 2.3, but they FORCE you when there are so many compatibility issues they can'T solve automatically...

Comment: To be honest I faced such an issue, for some cases I had to do it manually...

Comment: You still can have Xcode 7 and 8 near each other.

Comment: @Vahid It's 10,5G of space, would be 21G. What a waste. Probably I will have to do it like that.

Comment: @Martin. And concerting to swift 3 may take a lot of pain and time.